# Using SQLAdapter.Update(Dataset) Throws error "No primary key in select command"

Tags: c#, .net, sql, primary-key, dynamic-sql

In short, C# throws me "Dynamic SQL generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any key column information", while the table in question DOES have a Primary key (Identity, since it's MSSQL).

My code is as following:

```
       void loaddata()
    {
        try
        {
            DS = new DataSet();
            sqladapt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT servicetag,name,defect,primkey FROM " + Properties.Settings.Default.DBtableLaptops + "", sqlcon);
            sqladapt.FillSchema(DS, SchemaType.Source);
            sqladapt.Fill(DS);
            commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqladapt);
            DT = DS.Tables[0];
            Laptops_datagridview.DataSource = DT; //I'm using a datagridview to edit the data.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
    void savedata()
    {
        //Doesn't work yet.
        try
        {
            sqladapt.Update(DS); // <-- Throws the aforementioned error.
            sqladapt.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Data loading etc works fine, Adding new rows works aswell, and it saves it. But whenever i update or delete a row, it throws the error. 
Primkey is my primary key, it's an auto-incrementing integer.

I've been googling all day, but to no avail, the usual problem people have is that there is no primary key defined in the first place, but that's not the case here.

Any input would be greatly appreciated, i've been shotgun-debugging for like 6 hours now.

EDIT: 
The create statements for the table in question is as following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[laptopregistratieDB_laptops](
    [Servicetag] [text] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [text] NOT NULL,
    [Defect] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [primkey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Is PrimKey *actually* a primary key? IDENTITY and Primary Key are two separate concepts. Could you script the table from Management Studio and post the CREATE TABLE/ALTER TABLE statements?

Comment: I wasn't aware it was any different, i'm used to MySQL, and when i tried to create a database in MSSQL it didn't work, after some googling found i should use 'identifier' instead..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to actually make your primkey column a primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[laptopregistratieDB_laptops]
   ADD CONSTRAINT PK_laptopregistratieDB_laptops PRIMARY KEY (primkey)
```

You can also specify such a constraint when creating a table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[laptopregistratieDB_laptops](
    [Servicetag] [text] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [text] NOT NULL,
    [Defect] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [primkey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    constraint PK_laptopregistratieDB_laptops PRIMARY KEY (primkey)
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

or, if you want SQL Server to randomly generate the constraint name (not recommended, but some people do do it):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[laptopregistratieDB_laptops](
    [Servicetag] [text] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [text] NOT NULL,
    [Defect] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [primkey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

SQL Server will also randomly name the constraint if you apply a primary key constraint using the table designer (Right click next to the column you want to be primary key, choose "Set Primary Key")

All of these options can also be used to specify multi-column primary keys, with the exception of the `[primkey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY` variant. (In the designer scenario, you have to highlight multiple rows before right clicking).

Comment: I love you. This worked like a charm, i had no idea MSSQL's Identity was something different then a primary key, i just thought that was one of microsoft's gimicky ways again. Thanks a bunch again!

Answer (score 4):

Do you actually have a primary key in the table? If yes, check whether the primary key is set or not? Check the property `DS.DataTables[0].PrimaryKey`

Set the primary key in the `DataTable` inside the `DataSet`. You can do something like:

```
DS.DataTables[0].PrimaryKey  = DS.DataTables[0].DataColumns[3];
```

This will set the primary key for update.

Comment: DS.Tables[0].PrimaryKey was indeed not set, however, i had it set earlier and that even rendered me load data for some reason.. I'll try something with it.

Comment: If primary key is a text field (eg NVarChar), may throw error if max length is (MAX) rather than a number

Answer (score 0):

Error in line : `" sqladapt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT servicetag,name,defect,primkey FROM ...`, Because in your select query not include a field that is primary key or unique.

You need to fix your select SQL by adding a primary field in your table. For example:

```
sqladapt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ID, servicetag,name,defect,primkey FROM "
```

Hope this help!!!